# Swift: code crashing for some reason

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, unsafemutablepointer

I am a newbie in Swift and I am taking a course online but unfortunately they are not answering my question. I am sure the answer is easy but since I am a beginner, I am hoping people here can answer me.

```
import UIKit

public struct Pixel {
    public var value: UInt32 = 0

    public init() { }
    public var red: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8(value & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = UInt32(newValue) | (value & 0xFFFFFF00)
        }
    }

    public var green: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 8) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (value & 0xFFFF00FF)
        }
    }

    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 16) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (value & 0xFF00FFFF)
        }
    }

    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 24) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (value & 0x00FFFFFF)
        }
    }
}

public class RGBAImage
{
    public var pixels: [Pixel]

    public var width: Int
    public var height: Int
    private var imageData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>

    public init?(image: UIImage) {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }

        // Redraw image for correct pixel format
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue

        width = Int(image.size.width)
        height = Int(image.size.height)
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.allocate(capacity: width * height)

        guard let imageContext = CGContext.init(data: imageData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else { return nil }
        imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

        let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)
        pixels = Array(bufferPointer) // <-- is this creating a copy of that bufferPointer contents or a reference?

        imageData.deinitialize(count: width * height) // <-- I tried commenting out this code, so not to free the memory but to no avail. I am not sure if the previous line copied the buffer or kept a reference to it
    }

    public func toUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue

        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        let imageDataReference = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>(mutating: pixels)
        defer {
            imageDataReference.deinitialize(count: width * height)
        }
        let imageContext = CGContext(data: imageDataReference, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, releaseCallback: nil, releaseInfo: nil)

        guard let cgImage = imageContext!.makeImage() else {return nil}
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return image
    }
}

// Pixel visitor callback
public typealias PixelVisitor = (_ pixel: inout Pixel, _ args: AnyObject?) -> Void

public class ImageProcessor
{
    private var rgb_img: RGBAImage

    public init(img: UIImage) {
        rgb_img = RGBAImage(image: img)!
    }

    public func Pixels() -> [Pixel] {
        return rgb_img.pixels
    }

    public var width: Int {
        get {
            return rgb_img.width
        }
    }

    public var height: Int {
        get {
            return rgb_img.height
        }
    }

    public func visitPixels(_ callback: PixelVisitor, _ args: AnyObject?) {
        for y in 0..<self.rgb_img.height {
            let base = y * rgb_img.width
            for x in 0..<self.rgb_img.width {
                let index = base + x;
                var pixel = rgb_img.pixels[index]
                pixel.value += 0x202020 // <--- causing crash at index == 8?!
                //callback(&pixel, args)
            }
        }
    }

    public func toUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        return self.rgb_img.toUIImage()
    }
}
```

There are some questions in the code's comment above ("<--").
When I run the visitor, I get a crash when I try to modify the pixel at index == 8.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "sample")
var filter_man = ImageProcessor(img: image!)
filter_man.visitPixels({ (p, args) in
    //p.red += 30
}, nil)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message that it is crashing with?

Comment: Could be an integer overflow. What is `pixel.value` *immediately before* you add `0x202020` and it crashes?

Comment: Works for me, with a 200x200 image.

Comment: @MartinR Would you change `value` from a `UInt32` to `UInt64`?

Comment: @Adrian: `pixel.value` is a 32-bit integer with one byte for each color component (r, g, b, a), and directly corresponds to the memory representation of the bitmap. Changing the type does not help, an overflow has to be *handled* somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid this overflow – is to allow swift to do it

```
let res = pixel.value.addingReportingOverflow(0x202020)
pixel.value = res.partialValue
```

instead of your line with crash.

If you want to handle overflow and in that case make pixel white/black/red/ anything else – you could check it by overflow property on res in my example.

Comment: If you don't care about `overflow` flag value anyways, why don't you just use [`&+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2884804) operator? It's shorted too.